# New Mule version 3.7.0 gives timeout exception when i try to read feed via simple HTTP

Tags: http, mule, esb, connector

Just updated to mule esb version to 3.7.0 and end up breaking the system.
I just created simple HTTP connector to load feed from web site and its throwing timeout exception even after setting the max timeout as 2 minutes.

**Sample Code :**

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="www.theaggie.org" port="80" basePath="/feed/" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
    <http:proxy host="xxxxx" port="8080" username="xxxx" password="xxxx"/>
</http:request-config>
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/sfdc" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="hjkhh" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-property propertyName="User-Agent" value="MuleESB" doc:name="Property" mimeType="application/xml"/>
    <response>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </response>

</flow>
```

In the above code ,if i just keep the base path as baspath="/" ,then i am able to load the whole site.If i make the base path to point to feed as basePath="/feed/" then it throws the time out exception.This is applicable for all the site which has rss feeds.It doesn't work even after adding user agent as mule in set property or in direct URL.

Below is the exception :

INFO  2015-09-14 15:01:05,288 [[test].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: hjkhh
ERROR 2015-09-14 15:01:16,432 [[test].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
Payload               : {NullPayload}

---

Exception stack is:
1. Timeout exceeded (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider:463 (null)
2. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout exceeded
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.timeout(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:463)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$3.onTimeout(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter$DefaultWorker.doWork(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter$DefaultWorker.doWork(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I had a similar issue when connecting over a less than optimal public wifi connection. At first changing the connection timeout under the persistent connection setting in the global request property setting worked. But it success was intermittent. So, just connecting over my cellular data plan resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test with your code, but removed the proxy from the request-config and everything worked fine.

Code:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="www.theaggie.org" port="80" basePath="/feed/" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
</http:request-config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/sfdc" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="hjkhh" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-property propertyName="User-Agent" value="MuleESB" doc:name="Property" mimeType="application/xml"/>
        <response>
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </response>

</flow>
```

Then I called http://localhost:8081/sfdc and got the feed from theaggie.org. Does that work for you without the Proxy?