# mule ce 3.7.0 Exception when sending http-request - Timeout exceeded (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)

Tags: mule

I'm trying to send a http request from my jax-ws client to my own jaw-ws service. I've generated classes from wsdl and sending an ArrayList of objects with 60 items in it. But i'm getting exception.

Exception stack is:
1. Timeout exceeded (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider:426 (null)
2. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule
/api/MessagingException.html)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout exceeded
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.timeout(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:426)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$3.onTimeout(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter$DefaultWorker.doWork(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter$DefaultWorker.doWork(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide your flow.

Comment: I had the same issue. Only happened to me when I was on a questionable public network. Have you attempted to adjust the timeout setting on the request global properties under persistance? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557677/new-mule-version-3-7-0-gives-timeout-exception-when-i-try-to-read-feed-via-simpl

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved using the parameter `responseTimeout` in the `HTTP-Request` configuration:

```
<http:request-config responseTimeout="30000" {more parameters...} />
```

Set the value (in ms) to the time that you think best.